# Nhibernate Criteria For Select As

Tags: c#, sql, database, nhibernate

I would like to add to my criteria a specific column with an "as" addition.
Which means:
select 0 AS ID from XYZ ...

How can i do it, using a criteria ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate *Projections* are the feature you are looking for:

```
var projections = Projections.ProjectionList();
projections
  .Add(Projections.Property("EntityId"))
  .Add(Projections.Property("Code"))
  .Add(Projections.Constant(0), "ID"); // const projection

var list = session
  .CreateCriteria<MyEntity>()
  .SetProjection(projections) // projections
  .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(MyEntity)))
  .List<MyEntity>();
```

The first two (EntityId, Code) represent **mapped** *properties*. The last projection "ID" is const which could be set to **mapped** or **unmapped** property "ID"... of `MyEntity` class

Comment: My issue is a little different: The Id field is my key. I'm doing an outer join between two tables (one-to-many), and this Id is the key column. Now, i need that the id field to be with a zero value. for example: SELECT 0 as Id FROM XYZ LEFT OUTER JOIN ZZZ ON XYZ.ID = ZZZ.ID

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but what are you trying to do? The above SQL statement will return one column ID with as many 0 in rows as the XYZ table rowcount is... BTW, my answer is still suitable for that... Just one `Projections.Constant(0), "ID")`

Comment: If you do so, you'll get two columns - one of the original id (because we need to do a criteria with left outer join - UnitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<XYZDto>().CreateAlias("ZZZ", "zzz", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin) ) and one column with 0 values.  However, I need that the original id to be with a zero value...

Comment: no, i'm not :) ...  i'm talking about: SELECT codeId, codeName, date, sum(count), 0 AS id FROM XYZ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ZZZ ON XYZ.id= ZZZ.id
GROUP BY XYZ.codeId, XYZ.codeName, XYZ.date
ORDER BY XYZ.codeId

I just want to group it by other columns.

Comment: Ok, i was just stupid....  i did a group property of the id, and yet try to set it to const "0" :S
Sorry and many thanks ! :)  Actually, without chatting here, it would have take me a hour or two more...  (: